# Windows - is there a way to know/monitor who's taking screenshots?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, windows-11, screenshot

Sometimes when I paste things, instead of the content I copied, a screenshot of my entire screen gets pasted. It's as if I pressed PrtSc on my keyboard (I'm fairly sure I didn't), or a program is triggering print screen.

In case it's important (based on [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1595699/428812)), I have a stock Glorious GMMK Pro and its software is not installed.

Is there a way to know/log/monitor what's causing this? I would rather know what's causing it first before taking further steps.

Comment: I don't think so. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163909/is-there-any-way-to-detect-a-screen-capture-or-recording, https://superuser.com/questions/1359294/can-process-monitor-detect-if-a-screenshot-has-been-taken

Answer (score 1):

A tool that you may use to trace clipboard events on the computer is
[Sysmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon).

One of the events it creates is :

> **Event ID 24: ClipboardChange (New content in the clipboard)**
>
> This event is generated when the system clipboard contents change.

If you can locate the event that generated the clipboard image,
you will find the process that generated it.